# How to update values in multiple rows mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named jemaah :

```
   ID  name age gender
    1    a    2    p
    2    b    3    l
    3    c    1    l
    4    d    5    p
```

My question is how to update the value in gender column. For example i want to change the value p into f and l into m. All to together there are thousand rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE jemaah SET gender = 'f' WHERE gender = 'p';
UPDATE jemaah SET gender = 'm' WHERE gender = 'l';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE jemaah SET gender = CASE gender WHEN 'p' THEN 'f' WHEN 'l' THEN 'm' END
```

Answer (score 0):

2 updates need to be done

UPDATE *tablename*
 SET gender = "f"
WHERE gender = "p"

UPDATE tablename
SET gender = "m"
WHERE gender = "l"